# how to remote debug sonytv not in opera TV emulator

Tags: opera, remote-debugging, sony

I'm using operatv emulator for debugging. I want to know is there anyway to remote debug i.e my app running on Sony and logs on my systems console

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'd love to be able to debug directly within the emulator using some form of developer console.

Comment: Download Opera and start your TV emulator. In Opera go to localhost:5555 and a remote control should appear. On the remote is a "Connect to Dragonfly" button. Here is the docu https://dev.opera.com/tv/opera-tv-emulator/#debugging - Open the browsers dev console and select the "TV Emulator" window. I am not adding this as an answer, because the final step of actually seeing logs didn't work for me. But maybe it will for someone else?! If I can manage I will share it - but I am already trying since some days.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> Download Opera and start your TV emulator. In Opera go to localhost:5555 and a remote control should appear. On the remote is a "Connect to Dragonfly" button. Here is the docu dev.opera.com/tv/opera-tv-emulator/#debugging - Open the browsers dev console and select the "TV Emulator" window.

**References**

- [Dev.Opera — Opera TV Emulator User Guide](https://dev.opera.com/tv/opera-tv-emulator/)